# Keep application settings after changing application version

Tags: c#, application-settings

I am making an application with update included. Basically the update removes old application and creates a new one with a newer version. There aren't any setup configurations. Is there convinient way settings can be transferred to the application of new version?

Comment: How do you store your settings? Can you store settings in a file somewhere where it won't be overwritten?

Comment: what is your installation mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found solution. While program is updating, current settings are saved to .txt file and after update, program reads the text file and applies the settings